# How to write a update query for a child table having foreign key in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Table subject -> sub_code(primary key), sub_name, faculty

Table student -> student_id(primary key), student_name, sub_code, sub_name

Query:
Update student
Set student_id=11
Where student_id=10

Getting error because of foreign key

Comment: Also update the primary key in table 'subject'.

Comment: An example with deferrable constraints [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=47cb1f73e6aa5e2ae55901436c2a7b8e)